# Given equation $y^{\prime\prime\prime}+2y^{\prime\prime}-y^\prime-2y=0$, $y(0)=1$, $y^\prime(0)=0$, $^{\prime\prime}(0)=3$ find solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Given equation $y^{\prime\prime\prime}+2y^{\prime\prime}-y^\prime-2y=0$, $y(0)=1$, $y^\prime(0)=0$, $^{\prime\prime}(0)=3$ and 3 linearly independent solutions $y_1=e^x,y_2=e^{-x},y_3=e^{-2x}$ find a particular solution

I don't really understand what I'm supposed to do.

Is the solution supposed to be a combination of $y_p=c_1y_1+c_2y_2+c_3y_3$?

Comment: Use the Ansatz $y(x)=e^{\lambda x}$ to get that the general solution is $$y(x)=c_1 e^{-2 x}+c_2 e^{-x}+c_3 e^x$$
EDIT: Wait, you already have the solutions? The particular solution is $$\frac{2 e^{-2 x}}{3}-\frac{e^{-x}}{2}+\frac{5 e^x}{6}$$

Comment: What would be your procedure for solving the differential equation if you were not given initial conditions and were not given three linearly independent solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the solution should be some particular linear combination. You should use the required values for $y(0),y'(0)$ and $y''(0)$ to figure out what $c_1,c_2$ and $c_3$ need to be. (You will effectively set up a system of simultaneous equations.)